# Minimum number of elements on sphere to guarantee expected pairwise similarity is non-negative

Tags: linear-algebra, spheres

Given a set of N elements $X$ on the unit n-sphere $\mathbb{S}^n$ where $\forall \mathbf{x} \in X, ||\mathbf{x}||_2 = 1$. I would like to know if there is a minimum number of points required to guarantee:

$$ \sum_{\mathbf{x}_i, \mathbf{x}_j \in X  i \neq j}  \mathbf{x}_i^T \mathbf{x}_j \geq 0$$

My intuition is that for sufficiently many points in space, there is no configuration that has negative expected similarity as the expected maximum angle between points must decrease as a function of N.

Comment: No such $N$ exists, even for $n=1$: just take $N$ equally spaced points on the unit circle. For each fixed $i$, the sum over the remaining $j$ equals $\sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \cos\frac{2\pi k}N = -1$.

Comment: Fair enough! I am operating on the though that for infinitely spaced points the expected pairwise inner products is about 0. Thank you :)

Comment: The expected pairwise inner product is indeed $0$ by symmetry—but that isn't related to how many points there are overall.

Comment: Yeah! I see that now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such $N$ exists, even for $n=1$: just take $N$ equally spaced points on the unit circle. For each fixed $i$, the sum over the remaining $j$ equals
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \cos\frac{2\pi k}N = -1.
$$